# Adding edittext to CClayer in android cocos2d-1

Tags: android

How can I add edittext,textview to the CCLayer in android cocos2d-1?

I have tried this code:

```
CCDirector.sharedDirector().getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        final EditText name=new EditText(CCDirector.sharedDirector().getActivity());
        setView(name); 
    }
});
```

But here I want to setview to the CCLayer.